# Builder (Context) in Builder cannot be applied to (Context, java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have this error

`Builder(Context)in Builder cannot be applied to (Context, java.lang.String)`

On this line

```
`final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID);`
```

My build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.whrsmxmx.vk_api_test"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

How i can correct this code? If I clear the channel, then notifications come, there is a sound, but there is no pop-up window in the status bar.

Comment: @Nasodomlan Urban3p, You can use like this `final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    (Activity)mContext, CHANNEL_ID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It related to the version of "com.android.support:appcompat".

Just change the config to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'`
in the file build.gradle

And you may also need to add some configs.
like:

```
    repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
         maven{url "https://maven.google.com"}
    }
```

Comment: You see post date? It's not actual.

Comment: I just got the same problem yesterday and i solve it in this way.
May be people who got the same problem would see this.

Comment: This is underrated! This fixed it for me too!